# It says "No matching constructor for initialization of 'Fraction'

Tags: c++

.cpp

```
//
// calculator.cpp
//
#include "Fraction.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Fraction x,y; //ERROR IS RIGHT HERE. It says "No matching constructor for initialization of 'Fraction' 
    char op;
    try
    {
        cin >> x;
        cin >> op;
        while ( cin && ( op == '+' || op == '-' ) )
        {
            cin >> y;
            if ( op == '+' )
                x = x + y;
            else
                x = x - y;
            cin >> op;
        }
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    catch ( invalid_argument& e )
    {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

.h

```
#ifndef Fraction_Calculator_Fraction_h
#define Fraction_Calculator_Fraction_h
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

//Fraction class definition
class Fraction
{
public:

    Fraction (int a, int b);
    int fraction(int a, int b);
    void set(int, int);
    int get_numerator(void);
    int get_denomenator(void);
    int find_gcd (int n1, int n2);
    void reduce_fraction(int nump,  int denomp);
    Fraction& operator+(const Fraction& n);
    Fraction& operator-(const Fraction& n);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const  Fraction& n);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Fraction& n);
    Fraction& operator= (const Fraction& n);
    int denom;
    int numera;

private:
    int numerator;
    int denomenator;
    int denomp;
    int nump;

};

#endif
```

It says "No matching constructor for initialization of 'Fraction' on the first line of the cpp file
I don't understand what it means.

Comment: In this case we need to know about the contents of `Fraction.h`, otherwise there is no way to answer the question.

Comment: Also carefully read the information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), before asking next time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your Fraction constructor takes 2 arguments.

```
Fraction (int a, int b);
```

and you are invoking it with none

```
Fraction x,y; //ERROR IS RIGHT HERE. It says "No matching constructor for initialization of 'Fraction'
```

You should either invoke x and y with the 2 int parameters or define another constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: I tried this but then this error message came                        Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Fraction::operator=(Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      _main in calculator.o
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      _main in calculator.o
      _main in useFraction.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You are missing a whole load of code (at least you haven't posted it here) for the definitions of the functions in your Fraction class. You need to either define them inline in your header or else define them outside of the class definition preferably in a file called Fraction.cpp.

Comment: Look here http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/ to find out how to implement your << and >> operators.

Answer (score 0):

Provide default constructor like 
    Fraction()
    {
     numerator=0;
     denomenator0;
     denomp0;
     nump=0;
    }